# xib file open in xcode 5 but not open in xcode 4.6.2.

Tags: ios

Now I created my app in xcode5. Now I need to test the app in IOS6 so I open the app in xcode 4.6.2. While run my app it shows error in all my .xib file. Xib file can't be opened.

Comment: Try setting the "Opens in" tab in "Interface Builder Document" under File Inspector to Xcode 4.6

Comment: you cannot open xcode 5 .xib files in xcode 4.6.2 for testing see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you only want to test the application in IOS 6 there is no need of xcode 4.6.2 just install the IOS 6 Simulator in Xcode 5 and test it using that Simulator.

Press Xcode>Preferences>Downloads and install the desire Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Just compile your project with ios6.

You don't need xcode4.6.2 to run your project in ios6.

You can run your project in xcode5 with ios6.

Hope that helps you.